# Why is my libre office looking like old windows office?

Tags: 12.04, themes, libreoffice

I have ubuntu 12.04 and my libre office is looking just like windows office, the older one. How do I change the theme back the original one? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, that was it. I'm sorry, I just did not know what to search. Please put it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The question does not need an answer, it needs to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: You can't, only users with high rep can close.

Comment: so you do it. you have a hell of a reputation

Comment: Not enough to close a question by myself..